# Executing binary file on Oracle image goes to Exec format error

Tags: binaryfiles

I'm trying to take advantage of the oracle free tier instances.
Since the combo Oracle image let ampere shapes I chose this one (so changing for a more convenient distro is not possible).
I made a dnf upgrade and yum update
And I tried on WSL the same command works perfectly so the binary file is not corrupted.

The problem is when i'm trying to run a command I got the error:

```
-bash: ./geth: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

It seems I can have the infos with the commande uname and file :

```
$ uname -a
Linux instance-20240312-0845 5.15.0-203.146.5.1.el8uek.aarch64 #2 SMP Thu Feb 8 18:41:55 PST 2024 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux

$ file geth
geth: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[sha1]=576c5eb359cf8eee16f158e4a66bc7d1019c33d2, with debug_info, not stripped
```

For me it's compatible, both are on GNU/linux x64 vs aarc64 ? I'm clueless about what to do.

I made a dnf upgrade and yum update
And I tried on WSL the same command works perfectly so the binary file is not corrupted.

Comment: This does not appear to be about Oracle databases so I've removed the Oracle tag (which is only for Oracle database question, not other products from Oracle corp.). If there is a more appropriate tag then please [edit] your question and use that tag instead.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to run a x86_64 executable on ARM.  Recompile your program.